# QGIS Project Sync to Cloud gives API Error

Tags: qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I have been using QGIS and Qfield for a couple of months with no issues, however the last few times I have tried to sync a project to Qfield Cloud the conversion process fails and I get an error message:

> QFieldcloud rejected project creation [api_error] API Error

I have researched answers but found none.  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the software, creating a new Qfield cloud account and tried to sync on three different machines all with the same result.  I've also tried creating a new and very basic project and still fails.

How do I fix this?